# How to make regex match only whole words and not break the words down?

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a table of abbreviations for a document, and I'm using regex to find all abbreviations in the long string that is the Word document.

I'm using this pattern ' [A-Z]{2,6}-*[0-9]* '. This way, both "HCFC" and "HCFC-141" will be matched.

There are some section of the documents that are written in all caps. For example "ABSTRACT". And the previous pattern is returning "ABSTRA" and "CT" as two separate words. I want to match only whole words and remove both "ABSTRA" and "CT" from the list altogether. How do I do this?

PS. I've tried \b[A-Z]{2,6}-*[0-9]*\b and it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

PSS Python code:

```py
pattern = '[A-Z]{2,6}\-*[0-9]*'
abbreviation = re.findall(pattern,text)
```

is there a way to handle this using the re library?

Comment: Try `\b[A-Z]{2,6}(?:-[0-9]+)?\b`

Comment: Your regex match up to 6 letters ("{2,6}") and "ABSTRACT" has 8. So it was split into two valid regexes. Anyway, \b should enforce the presence of word limits, so ABSTRACT should fail and ABSTRA CT should pass.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks but it didn't work :/

Comment: Do you want to match ABSTRACT? Or should it be no match? Else try `\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:-[0-9]+)?\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird there should be no match for ABSTRACT

Comment: @flaviodesousa I get that part, but \b is not enforcing boundaries. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `{2,6}` and make sure to use word boundaries`\b` so that there are not 2 matches, one for `ABSTRA` and the other for `CT`

```
\b[A-Z]{2,6}(?:-[0-9]+)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xXHSYn/2)

In python:

```
regex = r"\b[A-Z]{2,6}(?:-[0-9]+)?\b"
```

If in thispart `-*[0-9]*` the hyphen is not optional you could turn it into an optional group `(?:-[0-9]+)?`

If there should not be anything on the left or right, you could use:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z]{2,6}-?[0-9]*(?!\S)
```

Note that `-*` will match 0 or more hyphens and `-?` matches an optional one.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xXHSYn/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that our problem might be just an optional group for the `-` followed by number, or maybe we wish to have word boundary, then this expression might work:

```
\b[A-Z]{2,6}(-[0-9]+)?\b
```

or

```
\b([A-Z]{2,6}(-[0-9]+)?)\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jL9Vd/1/)

```
###Test

# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\b([A-Z]{2,6}(-[0-9]+)?)\b"

test_str = ("HCFC\n"
    "HCFC-141\n"
    "aaHCFC-141")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 0):

try using r prefix.

```
pattern = r'\b[A-Z]{2,6}\-*[0-9]*\b'
abbreviation = re.findall(pattern,text)
```

This will not match the ABSTRACT, and matches to HDFC, HDFC-141 etc.

Comment: Spot on my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'ABSTRACT something HDFC, HDFC-141 and then some'
>>> pattern = r'\b[A-Z]{2,6}-*\d*\b'
>>> re.findall(pattern,text)
['HDFC', 'HDFC-141']
```